# creating input fields row automatically in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i am making the form for sales system so that user write data in one row and automatically row adds to add data for other products, i have a datagrid in wpf and i have input fields in datagrid, there are 6 fields in one row, what i need when i write in first field then automatically inputs fields row adds under the current row for new data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set `CanUserAddRows="True"` on datagrid, it will give you the functionality of automatically adding an empty row once the user is done editing the current row.

Thanks